# How to resolve "Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL"

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

Firstly I want to say that i checked all answers at stackoverflow, and i can't fix this bug! Help me please! I spend a lot of time, but no result.
I'm trying to create connection pool using Tomcat8.
I have an exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class
>   'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL
>   'jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/autopark'     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2160)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
>     at ua.khpi.shapoval.db.DbConnector.init(DbConnector.java:31)    at
>   ua.khpi.shapoval.db.DbContextListner.contextInitialized(DbContextListner.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
>     ... 13 more

**DbConnector.class**

```
public class DbConnector {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DbConnector.class.getName());
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    private static Connection connection;

    public static void init() throws ServletException, SQLException, NamingException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();

        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/");

        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/autopark");
        System.out.println(ds.getConnection());
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

**context.xml** that located in META-INF folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context crossContext="true" reloadable="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/autopark" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="root" password="161acid161" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/autopark" maxActive="15" maxIdle="3" />
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/autopark" global="jdbc/autopark"

        type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</Context>
```

**web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Autostation</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>


        <resource-ref>

            <description>Db</description>

            <res-ref-name>jdbc/autopark</res-ref-name>

            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>

        </resource-ref>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>ua.khpi.shapoval.db.DbContextListner</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Content of my **tomcat/lib** directory and my project structure.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that's the wrong name for the mysql connector driver. I recommend you to use Maven to manage your project dependencies

Comment: @Julian, i'm restricted by using Maven. I need to use Dynamic web project

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The JDBC URL is not correct, indeed you have a missing slash so try this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/autopark
```

If you check well the real error is **No suitable driver** which means that it cannot find any JDBC driver that supports the provided URL.

Comment: Man, I love you! Thanx a lot! One slash!!!!! I'm getting mad of this bug!

Comment: Oh yeah. I got `Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL '"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db"'`... nope, property files should not have quotes of any kind in them... apparently :|

Comment: @Erk - A stray " was the cause of my problem, thanks!