# Eclipse / Tomcat / Maven - rename context.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a strange problem. When I created the file *context.xml* in *META-INF*, I named it *contex.xml*.
I have a Spring project based on Maven and I use Eclipse. I have cleaned in many different way (Project menu > Clean, mvn clean install, clean/change of the server, etc.).
Now I have the famous error :

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

I am soneone very rigourous and this *contex.xml* kills me.

Do anyone have an idea of what to do to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774282/how-to-resolve-cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-for-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516747/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-i-do-not-underst

if you could not resolve the problem please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [1] Tomcat will ignore the **path** attribute if you place **context.xml** in **META-INF**. [2] If that is not the issue then update your post with the content of **META-INF/context.xml**, and your versions of Maven and Tomcat.